# Script within iframe not working

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm loading iframe like this

```
var fw = 600;
var fh = 300;
var left = (window.screen.width-fw)/2;
var top = (window.screen.height-fh)/2;
$.ajax('/app/ardeal/check_ardeals.htm', {
    data: {hookpoint: _hookpoint, lookupid: _lookupid},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res){
        if(res.status == "success"){
            $('body').append('<div class="fancybox-overlay fancybox-overlay-fixed" style="width: auto; height: auto; display: block;">' +
                '<div id="ard-container" style="visibility: visible; position: absolute; margin: auto; z-index: 99999; ' +
                'overflow: hidden; background-color: #efefef; width: '+fw+'px; top: '+top+'px; left: '+
                left+'px; display: block; background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">' +
                '<iframe id="ardeal-frame" scrolling="no" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: transparent;"' +
                'src="/app/ardeal/get_ardeal.html?lookupid='+_lookupid+'&hookpoint='+_hookpoint+'" height=100%></iframe></div></div>');
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr){
        //do nothing. Ignore.
    }
});
```

And here is my iframe content

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="#" id="skip_reward">No. Thank You.</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQuery = window.parent.jQuery;
        var $ = jQuery;
        window.onload = function(){
            window.parent.console.log("In iframe load");
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            window.parent.console.log("In iframe ready");
            $('#skip_reward').on('click', function(ev){
                ev.preventDefault();
                alert("Click within iframe");
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I see 'in iframe load' and 'in iframe  ready' printed in console. (Weird thing is twice. Any Ideas?). But my event is not getting bound. and when I click the link no alert is shown. How do I bind events to the elements inside the iframe from the script within the iframe?

Comment: Probably `$('#skip_reward')` tries to find an element from parent window, since you're referring the jQuery in the parent window. try this: `$('#ardeal-frame').contents().find('#skip_reward')`.

Comment: Yes I think this could be the reason. I loaded jquery within the iframe and removed jQuery and $ assignment then above code worked. One question though will it hamper performance loading jquery from main document as well as in iframe? Also my 'In iframe load' is printed twice. Any idea?

Comment: Rather not double load jQuery to `iframe`, they might conflict with each other. You could try to recognize the caller window by `console.log(e.target.document.title)`, if it's called from two different windows.